# jquery expanding menu how to?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to build a menu like this: http://wearebuild.com/

Try to click "Selected Works"

How can I make a div with child elements grow like it does in the menu?

Can anyone point me in a starting direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at the way they do it. The script is in there: http://wearebuild.com/wp-content/themes/build-2.5/js/wearebuild.min.js. It is minified but legible enough to find out which jQuery methods they are using.

Comment: That is because it is minified. If you have it formatted in a javascript editor you will get a feel for how they do it.